# Can Grafana be installed on a 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Tags: grafana

I did the following as instructed in the Grafana website:

`deb https://packagecloud.io/grafana/stable/debian/ wheezy main`

`curl https://packagecloud.io/gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install grafana`

No such package found

Is Grafana currently supported on 32bit Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official repo contains only 64 bit packages. There's [Github issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2525) for providing 32 bit package but no progress there.

You can try to build own binary, using [instructions on Github](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) repo and 32 bit VM.